# php file upload doesn't work on live server

Tags: php, image

Hey guys I'm following these tutorials on php image upload where user signs up creates an album and can upload images into a specific album.

file structure would be folder will be created in uploads and uploads/thumbs with user's id and all images from that user will be stored in there.

problem is my code works perfect on local server but on live server details get set to the database fine but no upload happens and no error returns...

file permissions are 744 755 in code and on the actual folders on server. Is there anything that comes to mind that I could try?

```
   function upload_image($image_temp, $image_ext, $album_id) {
    $album_id = (int)$album_id;

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `images` VALUES ('', '".$_SESSION['user_id']."', '$album_id', UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), '$image_ext')");

    $image_id = mysql_insert_id();
    $image_file = $image_id.'.'.$image_ext;
    move_uploaded_file($image_temp, 'uploads/'.$album_id.'/'.$image_file);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"images/". $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

    Thumbnail('uploads/'.$album_id.'/', $image_file, 'uploads/thumbs/'.$album_id.'/');
}
```

Comment: How big is the file size of your image? Do you upload to a shared web hosting? there might be a limit on the upload file size in php.ini

Comment: Is the uploads (and subdirectories) owned by the web server user? They would have to be in order for the permissions 744/755 to work. You could set permissions to 777 temporarily to see if there is a permission issue. You should also check the web server error log. Chances are you will see a php error there saying "permission denied" if this is the issue.

Comment: Hey iTech. images I tried uploading are 200kb or so, pretty small and I also have a condition in code. if ($image_size > 2097152) {
                $errors[] = 'Maximum file size is 2mb.';
            }

Comment: Awesome Jonathan just figured it after playing with the permissions on the server for quite a bit...